# Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spring, spring-security

Estou utilizando o Spring security 4.2.3 e o spring 4.2.5 quando executo a tela de login e a tela de cadastro de usuários funciona corretamente porem quando peço pra acessar a tela inicial. aparece esse erro:

```
messageCould not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.

descriptionAccess to the specified resource has been forbidden.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSRF significa [Cross Site Request Forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) e é uma espécie de ataque a sites. A documentação do Spring Security discute o assunto [neste link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html), é altamente recomendado que você leia essa tópico da documentação.

Você pode desabilitar o CSFR com o seguinte código no seu WebSecurityConfig:

```
  @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .csrf().disable();
        }
```

Este código e outros detalhes sobre o assunto podem ser vistos no segundo link passado no primerio parágrafo.